# Play 2.3.4 unable to create new project [TimeOut Exception]

Tags: java, playframework

I'm calling the activator to create a new project with the play-java template

```
activator new "projectName"
3
```

It always fail and I get the following error:

```
akka.pattern.AskTimeoutException: Ask timed out on [Actor[akka://default/user/te
mplate-cache#1973480390]] after [10000 ms]
    at akka.pattern.PromiseActorRef$$anonfun$1.apply$mcV$sp(AskSupport.scala
:333)
    at akka.actor.Scheduler$$anon$7.run(Scheduler.scala:117)
    at scala.concurrent.Future$InternalCallbackExecutor$.unbatchedExecute(Fu
ture.scala:599)
    at scala.concurrent.BatchingExecutor$class.execute(BatchingExecutor.scal
a:109)
    at scala.concurrent.Future$InternalCallbackExecutor$.execute(Future.scal
a:597)
    at akka.actor.LightArrayRevolverScheduler$TaskHolder.executeTask(Schedul
er.scala:467)
    at akka.actor.LightArrayRevolverScheduler$$anon$8.executeBucket$1(Schedu
ler.scala:419)
    at akka.actor.LightArrayRevolverScheduler$$anon$8.nextTick(Scheduler.sca
la:423)
    at akka.actor.LightArrayRevolverScheduler$$anon$8.run(Scheduler.scala:37
5)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I tried to increase the timeout:

```
activator -Dactivator.timeout=30s
```

but I get the exception in less than a second regardless.

Comment: Add issue to https://github.com/playframework/playframework/issues/

Comment: I just tried this same command on my local computer and it works fine. Are you on Windows or Mac?  Are you sure your local firewall isn't blocking any ports?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default Activator has a 10 second timeout to fetch the latest templates and check for a new version. 
On slow internet connections it might be necessary to increate that timeout.

For example

```
activator -Dactivator.timeout=30s new "project name"
```

Or you can put that parameter into your ~/.activator/activatorconfig.txt file.